# (concept Confusion) App\User::role must return a relationship instance (eloquent relation work but query builder not working)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**I am creating AdminAuthenticated middleware**

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role->name == 'customer') {
            return redirect('/home')->with('message', 'You are not allowed to access');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**My Question is** 
when i use eloquent relation it will work fine but when i use query builder its throw error

> **This code works**

```
   public  function role(){
       //this code work
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
   }
```

> **This code throw error why this happen and how to use below code(query builder)**

```
    public  function role(){
        //this code not work throw exception
        return DB::table('users')
            ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
            ->select('roles.*')
            ->where('users.id','=',$this->id);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to use the query builder method you have to add an `->first()` to execute the query and get the first result

Comment: @JulianS sir i add ->first() but not working , same error throw

Comment: And in your middleware you have to modify your if to use `->role()` instead of `->role` because it is a function returning a role object and not a relationship

Answer (score 0):

because the relation is many to many ...there is a pivot table between users and roles tables..

in 'join' you can not ignore pivot tables....

if you are using [Spatie](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/installation-laravel/)

then your 'join' should be:

```
public  function role(){

        return DB::table('users')
            ->join('model_has_roles',function($join){
$join->on('users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')
where('model_has_roles.model_type','=',User::class);}) )


->join('roles','roles.id','=','model_has_roles.role_id')
            ->select('roles.*')
            ->where('users.id','=',$this->id);
    }
```

note: i recommend renaming your method to 'roles' instead of 'role'